# Как правильно отправить команду на устройство по BluetoothLowEnergy?

Tags: android, kotlin

Я успешно подключаюсь к устройству и получаю характеристику для записи, которые соответствуют uuid'ам в API

В API есть вот такой пример команды:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал отправлять всяко по-разному, но получается какая-то ахинея. Основной вариант такой:

```
characteristic.writeType = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT
characteristic.setValue(byteArrayOf(0x50, 0x4c, 0x01, 0x10))
bluetoothGatt?.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)
```

Но, никакого ответа я не получаю.
Точнее, срабатывает callBack "onCharacteristicWrite", а status: Int в нём соответствует длине массива байт, который я отправил.

Совершенно не понимаю в чём проблема, но основная теория - я как-то неправильно отправляю запрос. Но вся инфа по этому поводу, которая у меня есть - на скрине.

(Подключение успешно, сервис и характеристику, которой доступно чтение и запись тоже получаю успешно)*

Comment: А какой ответ вы ожидаете? Вам BLE stack подтвердил, что данные отправил. Остальное на том устройстве, как оно на команду реагирует читайте в документации. Обычно в одну характеристику пишешь, а в другой читаешь результат.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Я ожидаю помощи). Мне казалось, что статус в коллбэкэ говорит о неуспешности отправления, но если он связан с величиной отправляемого массива - статус просто сообщает сколько данных пришло, я правильно понимаю? И ещё вопрос, если вам не затруднит. Когда подписываться на чтение характеристики или уведомления - до или после отправки данных? Потому что я пробовал подписываться на чтение до отправки - в итоге данные не отправлялись вообще и коллбэк не срабатывал. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: В `onCharacteristicWrite` статус должен приходить 0 (GATT_SUCCESS), смотрите возможные ошибки в списке констант: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt#GATT_SUCCESS

Comment: "подписываться на чтение" - это как? Просто читаете характеристику в любое время, для этого никакой подписки не надо, данные придут в `onCharacteristicRead`. Подписаться можно на уведомления о изменении характеристики (если она это поддерживает), тогда вам новые данные будут сразу приходить в `onCharacteristicChanged`.

Comment: Хороший цикл статей о BLE Android, рекомендую к изучению, там многие подводные камни описаны: https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-1-a736dcd53b02